# I18n of "This application is out of date" GWT

Tags: gwt, internationalization, gwt-rpc, gxt

We are doing hotfixes/new releases every 2/3 days, so our users are experiencing that annoying "This application is out of date" message frequently. So, until we develop a way to check if app is out of date and force the reload, we would like to, at least, internationalize the message, as most of our users are not using english version of the app and looks weird.

Is there a way to i18n that "This application is out of date" message?

EDIT: As far as I've read, although I haven't tried it yet, maybe catching `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException` and doing the I18n there could do the trick. But we've lots of RPC calls... is there a nicer (yes, I mean easier and faster) way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a much better aproach (at least for my workflow). It consists in not informing user to reload, but avoid it.

The way I do that is by forcing browsers not to cache the *noncache.js file. This can be done by creating a filter and adding it to the app web.xml.
The following is the `doFilter()` code.

```
if (requestURI.contains(".nocache.")) {
 Date now = new Date();
 HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
 httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
 httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
}
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Then, just add the filter mapping `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` and you got it! Transparent changes to the user :D

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's of course a reason the files are called nocache.js and cache.is/html. Your "solution" doesn't support the use case of updating the app while it's currently open by users. They'll only have the new version if they refresh, but in the mean time will have `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException`.

Comment: Yes, I know that, we are now working on that. We have the problem on opened sessions, but on new sessions we solve the problem by that approach. So we reduce the time all users get on new versions. I guess we will finally do what you suggested me, but haven't had time enough to solve it. I'll let you know!

Comment: BTW, it is documented that you shouldn't cache the nocache.js files: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#perfect_caching Sure there's only Apache configuration given as example, but at least you already had the information.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException`s globally using a [`GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29). There, use an `instanceof IncompatibleRemoteServiceException` check and display whatever error message in whatever way to the user (e.g. Google Groups uses the same kind of "bubble" as for "loading…" and "your message has been sent" indicators, along with a "Reload" link).

Of course, that's if your `AsyncCallback`s re-throw the exception.

Comment: Woho! Nice approach! Althoug my AsyncCallbacks aren't re-throwing exceptions. But all our `AsyncCallbacks` are `MyOwnAsyncCallback<T>`, which implements `AsyncCallback<T>`, so I guess I can do a workaround here, using the `instance of IncompatibleRemoteServiceException` instead of doing 1500 times the same catch. Sometimes we can`t see forest for the trees!

Thank you so much!